# How to convert a multi-page PDF to single-page TIFFs

Tags: pdf, converters, tiff, ghostscript, multipage

This thread asks for how to convert multi-page PDF to ***multi-page*** TIFF with Ghostscript;

- **["Tools to convert multipage PDF to multipage TIFF"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037101/tools-to-convert-multipage-pdf-to-multipage-tiff)**

However, I want to covert a multi page PDF to a number of ***single-page*** TIFFs: Each page in the PDF is expected to be converted to a single TIFF file. So the above answer does not exactly match what I need.

How can I achieve this?

I am using Windows XP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools to convert multipage PDF to multipage TIFF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037101/tools-to-convert-multipage-pdf-to-multipage-tiff)

Comment: The simple answer is to use the '%d' syntax in OutputFile. Eg -sOutputFile=out%d.tif. IMO the question isn't too broad, there's one good answer and its not too long.

Comment: I just noticed that although this is tagged as Ghostscript, its not clear the OP knows how to use GS, though the answer already referenced does contain the basic information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to have a *recent* version of Ghostscript installed. Then you can run these commands:

```
gs                              \
  -o singlepage-tiffg4-%03d.tif \
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4               \
   multipage-input.pdf
```

and

```
gs                                \
  -o singlepage-tiff24nc-%03d.tif \
  -sDEVICE=tiff24nc               \
   multipage-input.pdf
```

and

```
gs                                \
  -o singlepage-tiff32nc-%03d.tif \
  -sDEVICE=tiff32nc               \
   multipage-input.pdf
```

The commands will generate you 3 sets of TIFF files. Each set contains singlepage TIFFs which carry names that contain an index numbers starting with `001`:

```
ls -lt singlepage-tiff*.tif

 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  161975 18 Feb 15:49 singlepage-tiffg4-001.tif
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  169294 18 Feb 15:49 singlepage-tiffg4-002.tif
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  167397 18 Feb 15:49 singlepage-tiffg4-003.tif
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  190052 18 Feb 15:49 singlepage-tiffg4-004.tif
```

If you have *a lot* of PDF pages per file, you can increase the number of digits/leading zeros to a higher number: use `%05d` to get a 5 digit numbering.

The three different commands generate different types of TIFF:

1. The *tiffg4* ones are grayscale TIFFs.
   They use a resolution of 204dpi by 196dpi (as the TIFF G4 fax standard requires).
2. The *tiff24nc* ones are in RGB color (with 8 bits per color component).
   They use a resolution of 72dpi by 72dpi.
3. The *tiff32nc* ones are in CMYK color (with 8 bits per color).
   They  also use a resolution of 72dpi.

All the resolution values for the TIFF files result from Ghostscript's default settings. If you want to override these, for example because you require 600dpi by 600dpi, just add

```
-r600x600
```

to any of the above command lines.